# Why are the powers of an element in an integral domain infinite?

Tags: ring-theory

A proof I'm reading claims that in if $r$ is a non-zero member of an integral domain $R$, then the set $\{1, r, r^2, ...\}$ is infinite. I can't seem to prove this is the case. I get as far as showing that if the set is finite, then some power of $r$ is equal to the multiplicative identity, and after that I can't seem to obtain any kind of contradiction.

Comment: The statement cannot be true, if $R$ is a finite integral domain, and these exist (e.g. $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ for a prime $p$). Worse, even if $R$ is infinite it may fail, (consider $R=\Bbb{C}$ and $r$ a root of unity).

Comment: What about $Z_5$ for example ? the set of powers of any elements is a subset of $Z_5$ hence finite

Comment: @NilsMatthes See my comment under rschwieb's answer.

Comment: I highly suspect "nonunit" was omitted from the problem statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because there's something missing from the statement.

For $r=1$, the powers are trivially a finite set!

Furthermore, for any $n$-th root of unity in $\Bbb C$, the powers are a finite set, so that is a counterexample to the statement of the problem also.

---

You could make it a true statement this way: For any nonzero *nonunit* $r$ in a domain, the set of powers of $r$ is infinite. From your own work so far, you can prove this.

Comment: But the conclusion of the proof is that $r$ *does* have a multiplicative inverse. I didn't mention that $R$ is assumed to be a finite-dimensional vector space over some field $F$, is that relevant?

Comment: @JackM Think about it: If you assume $r$ is a nonunit and has finitely many powers you conclude it is a unit and get a contradiction. Thus the powers of a nonzero nonunit form an infinite set!

Comment: @JackM Assuming $R$ is a domain which is a finite dimensional vector space over a field is not a good way to improve the statement. A domain that's a finite dimensional vector space over a subfield is a field itself, so it just makes for a convoluted problem statement.

Comment: Now I think about it, I suppose the point of the proof is to show that $r$ has an inverse, so if it's already a unit you're done anyway.

Comment: @JackM Oh, now that I reread your question I see you are alluding to some proof that I can't see, not the question itself. Sorry about the clutter :) I was confused because I have no idea what the proof is about.

Comment: @JackM Are you by any chance proving the theorem I mentioned in my second comment above?

Comment: That $R$ is a field? Yes.

Comment: @JackM Hrm, I think there are more straightforward proofs. Personally, I like to show everything is a unit in this way: given a basis $b_1,\dots b_n$ for $R$ and nonzero element $r$, $rb_1,\dots, rb_n$ is also a basis for $R$. But then $\sum \alpha_irb_i=r(\sum\alpha_ib_i)=1$ for some set of $\alpha$'s. You will probably find two or three other proofs in questions on this site.